# Why is this warning "Expected type 'int' (matched generic type '_T'), got 'Dict[str, None]' instead"?

Tags: python, pycharm

Please watch carefully the question and carefully the answers of [this and you'll see it's not a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797011/what-does-this-warning-in-pycharm-mean), especially because they dont answer my question.

Try to make a new empty project, and add this code. It works fine without warnings:

```
game_data = {'boats': [], }
game_data['boats'].append({'name': None})
```

Now change it to:

```
game_data = {'boats': [], 'width': None, 'height': None, }
game_data['boats'].append({'name': None})
```

Still no warnings.
And change again to:

```
w = 12
game_data = {'boats': [], 'width': None, 'height': w, }
game_data['boats'].append({'name': None})
```

And now you'll get:

```
Expected type 'int' (matched generic type '_T'), got 'Dict[str, None]' instead
```

Am I the only one to have this? And why is this? Is there a solution to make this warning go away?

Comment: not on VS 2017 python 3.6 not in pyfiddle.io , maybe a pycharm speciality?

Comment: I agree. I have no warnings either in Visual Studio Code. Must be PyCharm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this warning in PyCharm mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797011/what-does-this-warning-in-pycharm-mean)

Comment: Please watch carefully the question and carefully the answers of what you think is a duplicate, and you'll change your mind

Comment: I am not suggesting anything. I use VS2017 sometimes and for simple stuff even pyfiddle.io. I do not endorse anything. Use whatever suits you - I merely observed that for the same code blocks you postet I get no warning in either IDE _**I**_ use so they might be IDE-Dependent. I will review the other post I thought a duplicate, gimme a sec.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My *guess* would be the analytics that give this warning are not sharp enough.

The value type for

```
game_data = {'boats': [], 'width': None, 'height': None}
```

can not be determined.

The first "real" value you put in is an int:

```
w = 12
game_data = {'boats': [], 'width': None, 'height': w}
```

So PyCharm *assumes* that this is a `dict(string->int)`.

Then you add a inner dict as value to your empty list:

```
game_data['boats'].append({'name': None})
```

So now it has a dict(string->int) that suddenly gets to be a mixed thing and warns you.

Thats about the same as what [What does this warning in PyCharm mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797011/what-does-this-warning-in-pycharm-mean) is about: adding `int` into a `list of string`s using pycharm as IDE.

As to how to get rid of the warning: Jetbrains Resharper is very configurable, I guess pycharm will be as well. This documentation https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-inspection-severities.html#severity might help you configure the severity down - if not I am sure the support of Jetbrains is eager to help you out - they were whenever I had problems using resharper.

Comment: I prefer to add a "# noinspection PyTypeChecker" above the line in causing the warning, this makes it explicit for the next person reading the code, that this is known and should be ignored.

Comment: You can also resolve it by adding a hint like `game_data: dict[str, Any]`